# Woocommerce role: shop_manager > create_users - role dropdown

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, roles

My woocommerce Shop Manager can add new users, but adding new user > role dropdown is offer only customer role.
Is there some fix how to give permission to select from all roles not only "customer"

Code:

```
function add_theme_caps_1() {
        $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
        $role->add_cap( 'add_users' ); 
        $role->add_cap( 'create_users' ); 
        $role->add_cap( 'delete_users' ); 
        $role->add_cap( 'create_users' );
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_users' );
        $role->add_cap( 'promote_users' );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps_1');
```